# How to make document ready conditional using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS as my framework. I've a link which send request to MCV Action and finally gets forwarded to view.  This view has registered JavaScript File which loads angular.element(document).ready(function (e){} function. Basically I'm trying to create a if else statement inside angular.element(document).ready. based on myparam=true. How can I do it?

Link -

```
"<h7>" + "" + "<a target=\"_blank\" href='/Submission/EditSubmissionFile?id=" + SubmissionID + "&myparam=true" +"'>" + "Add Attachment" + "</a><br></h7>" +
```

AngularJS Javascript File -

```
mainApp.controller('editSubmissionFileController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'viewDataService', 'utilityService', '$window', 'constants', '$timeout', 'constants', 'adComplianceUtility', 'submissionRuleService',
    function ($scope, $location, $http, viewDataService, utilityService, $window, constants, $timeout, constants, adComplianceUtility, submissionRuleService) {
        
        angular.element(document).ready(function (e) {
        
        // How to make this conditional based on parameter passed from Action or html link? 

        $scope.$broadcast('ShowFileUpload', {
            SubmissionID: $scope.model.data.SubmissionID,
            Show: true,
            Callback: function (data) {
                $scope.onFileUploadSuccessful(data);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Action -

```
public ActionResult EditSubmissionFile(int id)
        {
            // We can only see what we are allowed
            UserContext.TestSubmissionExists(id);
            UserContext.TestSubmissionAccess(id, AccessRightEnum.ViewSubmissions);

            var model = _submissionSvc.GetSubmissionViewModel(id);

            return View("EditSubmissionFile", model);
        }
```

Comment: Really not clear what higher level problem you are trying to solve here. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Are you asking how to bootstrap the angular app only if url has a specific value?

Comment: I'm trying to create a if else statement inside angular.element(document).ready. based on myparam=true. How can I do it?

Comment: charlietfl - Yes, very similar. I need to get the value myparam=true that is passed from URL. next create a conditional statement in angular.element(document).read function.

Comment: Use [URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Nice! Actually that reminds me if I use simple window.location.href and check the parameter value, it works as expected. Thank you for the quick tips! helped me to think differently rather thinking always complex. Posting the solution soon.

Comment: You could also pass a variable from back end in a script tag and check it's value

Comment: I tried adding a flag in model. Not sure why it was not saying undefined in Javascript. This is what I tried alert($scope.model.showdialog). // Here showdialog is set to true in backend model (inside action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a simple window.location.href and check if parameter exists in URL does the job. Sometimes simple is better! Thank you.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function (e) {
            // Check if URL contains a parameter value to restrict default pageload function.
            if (window.location.href.indexOf("myparam=true") > -1)
            {
                $scope.$broadcast('ShowFileUpload', {
                    SubmissionID: $scope.model.data.SubmissionID,
                    Show: true,
                    Callback: function (data) {
                        $scope.onFileUploadSuccessful(data);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```